# Tomcat unable to access JARs in Spring3 WAR file

Tags: spring, tomcat6, spring-ws

I am developing a SOAP web service using Spring 3.0, Spring-WS, SpringSource toolsuite running tc server v6.   When I run the application on the server, I get the following exception in SpringSource toolsuite.

```
type Exception report message description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request. exception javax.servlet.ServletException: 
        Wrapper cannot find servlet class org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet or a class it depends on 
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:60)      
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)      
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)      
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)      
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)     
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:379)      
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)      
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)      
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)"
```

The org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet  class is contained within the spring-ws-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar which is on my classpath. I have verified that the .JAR is contained within the WAR file but still getting the above exception.

This error occurs in both a stand-alone installation of Tomcat, and the embedded TC Lite server distributed with the STS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing some other dependent jar.

```
Wrapper cannot find servlet class org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet or a "class it depends on"
```

The depends on, check the pom dependencies for the ws-core. Try modifying the pom scope for the ws-core to compile (from provided if it is so)

Comment: It was a deep dependency that was scoped as 'provided'. We needed to go through several layers of POM files to see the dependencies. For some reason `mvn dependency:tree` doesn't list 'provided' scoped dependencies more than 1 or 2 levels deep. Anyway, we just put an explicit dependency on the JAR with no scope. May cause more problems in a run-time environment, we'll see!